# Equivalent of for loop in Red?

Tags: rebol, red

I want to use for http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wfor.html
for Red it doesn't work.

What's the equivalent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **for** in Rebol2 is just a mezzanine, you can write your own for

```
for: func [
    "Repeats a block over a range of values." 
    [catch throw] 
    'word [word!] "Variable to hold current value" 
    start [number! series! time! date! char!] "Starting value" 
    end [number! series!  time! date! char!] "Ending value" 
    bump [number!  time! char!] "Amount to skip each time" 
    body [block!] "Block to evaluate" 
    /local result do-body op
][
    if (type? start) <> (type? end) [
        throw make error! reduce ['script 'expect-arg 'for 'end type? start]
    ] 
    do-body: func reduce [[throw] word] body 
    op: :greater-or-equal? 
    either series? start [
        if not same? head start head end [
            throw make error! reduce ['script 'invalid-arg end]
        ] 
        if (negative? bump) [op: :lesser?] 
        while [op index? end index? start] [
            set/any 'result do-body start 
            start: skip start bump
        ] 
        if (negative? bump) [set/any 'result do-body start]
    ] [
        if (negative? bump) [op: :lesser-or-equal?] 
        while [op end start] [
            set/any 'result do-body start 
            start: start + bump
        ]
    ] 
    get/any 'result
]
```

but you can find also a few mightier or more c-syntax-like versions on the net e.g. a [proposal for Rebol3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706547/c-style-for-loops-in-rebol)

```
cfor: func [  ; Not this name
    "General loop based on an initial state, test, and per-loop change."
    init [block! object!] "Words & initial values as object spec (local)"
    test [block!] "Continue if condition is true"
    bump [block!] "Move to the next step in the loop"
    body [block!] "Block to evaluate each time"
    /local ret
] [
    if block? init [init: make object! init]
    test: bind/copy test init
    body: bind/copy body init
    bump: bind/copy bump init
    while test [set/any 'ret do body do bump get/any 'ret]
]
```

Red also offers the possibility to define your own macro and compile it.